# Find intersection location on MySQL

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a table with this structure

```
(location_name, address, latitude, longitude)
```

First, user entered two locations name and two radius.

Second, database find latitude and longitude about entered location.

(Hereinafter, it is called 'entered_lat' and 'entered_long'.)

Third, the database finds and returns locations that are located at the intersection of two radius that user entered.

When,the user entered only one location and radius, I used the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT location_name, latitude, longitude, 
(6371*acos(cos(radians('entered_lat'))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-
radians('entered_long'))+sin(radians('entered_lat'))*sin(radians(latitude))))
AS distance FROM location_table HAVING distance < 'entered_radius';
```

So, I tried to use the following SQL statement to find the intersection of two radius.

```
SELECT location_name, latitude, longitude, 
(6371*acos(cos(radians('entered_lat1'))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-
radians('entered_long1'))+sin(radians('entered_lat1'))*sin(radians(latitude))))
AS distance FROM location_table HAVING distance < 'entered_radius1'
 AND 
(6371*acos(cos(radians('entered_lat2'))*cos(radians(latitude))*cos(radians(longitude)-
radians('entered_long2'))+sin(radians('entered_lat2'))*sin(radians(latitude))))
AS distance FROM location_table HAVING distance < 'entered_radius2';
```

But that SQL statement has syntax error.

What should I do that the database returns locations that are located at the intersection of two radius that user entered?

Comment: The error message says `... near '...'` -- please provide that.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace l_name with location_name in your SQL statement.

Comment: That's typo. I'm sorry.